# Rxjs map array of objects

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I want to map array of object
Now I have something like that

```
return this.service.post(url, payload, this.httpOptions)
    .pipe(
        map((obj: any, index) => [({
            ...obj,
            val1: obj[index].val1.id,
            val2: obj[index].val2.id
        })]
    ))
```

I aslo try do in that way

```
  map((obj: any, index) => 
        {   
            const list = []
            const obj = { 
                ...obj,
                val1: obj[index].val1.id,
                val2: obj[index].val2.id
            }
            list.push(obj);
            return list;
        }
```

Input

```
 [
  {
    "val1": { "id": "USER_ID", "value": "User1" },
    "val2": { "id": "USER_ID", "value": "User2" },
    "val3": "aaa",
    "val4": "val2"
  },
  {
    "val1": { "id": "USER_ID", "value": "User3" },
    "val2": { "id": "USER_ID", "value": "User4" },
    "val3": "dds",
    "val4": "eee"
  }
]
```

and expected output

```
   [
    {
      "val1": "USER_ID",
      "val2": "USER_ID",
      "val3": "aaa",
      "val4": "val2"
    },
    {
      "val1": "USER_ID",
      "val2": "USER_ID",
      "val3": "dds",
      "val4": "eee"
    }
]
```

Now Instead array of object I have array with one object that contains all objects
I want to have array of object and each object contains obj plus mapped values in example val1 and val2

Comment: Remove [( and )] from map()

Comment: map((obj: any) => {
            ...obj,
            val1: obj.result.id,
            val2: obj.status.id
        })

Comment: if remove I have { 0: {}, 1: {}, val1: '...', val2: '...' }

Comment: please post your data shape for input and desired output.  It seems like @BeshambherChaukhwan is right, removing `([` and `])` should work.

Comment: actually, only remove the square brackets, the parentheses  are still needed.

Comment: Nah there are multiple parentheses look closely. The one which is enclosing the map will still be there

Comment: `map` with the square brackets should have given you an array of arrays, with each subarray having a single object. You'll want to provide the shape of the `obj` argument though, because `obj[index]` doesn't make much sense, since `index` is the index of `obj` in the outer array.

Comment: @WalterWhite you are still returning an array inside array in your updated code. Let me make the answer

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in your `map()` operator.  It receives the full payload, not the individual items!  So what you are calling `obj` is really an array. So you need to also use `.map()` on the array.

Also, you do not need the `index` since your property is on the object itself.

```js
    map(inputArray => inputArray.map(obj => ({
      ...obj,
      val1: obj.val1.id,
      val2: obj.val2.id
    })))
```

Here's a working [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-66533165?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using `.map()` on the response body data which is expected to be an array then the returned result of it would also be an array and you don't need to club it again in another array in the map callback function. And for the second requirement of adding extra key value pairs in each elements of the response, your existing code by using spread operator is fine. Try this for your map fix:

```
return this.service.post(url, payload, this.httpOptions)
    .pipe(
        map((obj: any) => {
          return {
            ...obj,
            val1: obj.val1?.id,
            val2: obj.val2?.id
         }
      })
   )
```

This will give the expected output as

[ {key1: value, ..., val1: value, val2: value}, ... ]

Check the sample code: https://ideone.com/stVusF

Comment: This doesn't do what you think it does, and is the reason BizzyBob said to keep the parentheses in. Brackets after an arrow put the arrow function into "statement mode" rather than "return mode", so you should get syntax errors from that code.

Comment: Ohhh yes yes I forgot. Thanks

Comment: But if I add `return` and remove the parentheses, it would be the same thing right?

Comment: You would need to add another set of brackets to use `return`.

Comment: Hmmm like this right `.map(a => { return { ... } })`

Comment: If I use that I have error Cannot read property 'id' of undefined that's why I used index

Comment: Should be `val1: obj.val1.id, val2: obj.val2.id`

Comment: it's strange because the object on the input contains an id and gets an error that cannot read property 'id' of undefined.
and I have val1: obj.val1.id, val2: obj.val2.id

Comment: Give us a moment we will check again

Comment: @WalterWhite Check now with this sample code https://ideone.com/stVusF

Comment: I have no idea why Instead array of the object has that form and for test, I change 
val1: obj.val1.id to val1: obj.val3 and return me that form {0: {...}, 1: {..}..., val1: undefinded }

Comment: Show us the exact console.log of your response with and without `map()`